# Can't authenticate to npm.fontawesome.com registry to install pro packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I have configured my host globally as described in [font awesome documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers)

I am running the following:

```
npm config set "@fortawesome:registry" https://npm.fontawesome.com/
npm config set "//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken" "${NPM_FONT_AWESOME_AUTH_TOKEN}"
```

I have the following error:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="https://npm.fontawesome.com/"
```

I expect to authenticate.

If you access from a browser https://npm.fontawesome.com/ , you have a Basic auth, I am not sure what I should expect here as I have never tried before.

This happened recently, the configuration was working for year. Is it me or fontawesome server?

How to fix fontawesome npm authentication?

Comment: Sounds like a question for Font Awesome support. You're paying for it, use it ;).

Comment: IT seems that my subscription ended on ` Jan 16, 2020`, but I should be able to access `Version 5.12.0`, I have thhe perpetual license on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FontAwesome does not keep your access active despite you have a license for one or more versions. The one way to get permanent access to your font awesome package is to host it on your own private registry or on a paid npm account.

Be aware that the provided files in direct download are not exactly the same as the npm package.

I advise fontawesome user to keep a copy of the distributed package to avoid checksum issue with lock files.

Comment: The provided files in direct download are not to be used as packages then ? How to create the packages ?

Comment: This makes no sense. Having a license does not give access? What does it give then?

Answer (score 21):

I am also got this same error!.. Below mentioned steps working for me...

***Solutions***

**Step 1 :** npm config delete "@fortawesome:registry" https://npm.fontawesome.com/

**Step 2 :** npm install / npm install <package_name>

or

otherwise add npm username & password.

Comment: Thank you. This actually solved an issue trying to download the svg-core with an expired license

Comment: Executing the `npm config delete`-command fixed my issue of not being able to install the free version using `$ npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
` in their [Documentation](https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/setup/packages#set-up-npm-token-for-all-projects).

Answer (score 0):

npm install in windows make two files npmrc i remove that line and solve problem!

Comment: you may find this file   
C:\Users\<Your User Name>\.npmrc

Comment: Your text is not very clear. Using dot and uppercase symbols to make two sentences would help. What are the names of these two files you mention ? What line you removed ? Thanks.